# jQuery, how do I call a url by checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<span id="social">
    Facebook:
    <input id="id_connected_to_facebook" type="checkbox" name="connected_to_facebook">
    <br>
    Twitter:
    <input id="id_connected_to_twitter" type="checkbox" name="connected_to_twitter">
    <br>
</span>
```

and with jQuery I would like to call a different URL for all the 4 possible actions (1: check facebook, 2: uncheck facebook, 3: check twitter, 4: uncheck twitter).

How would I do that?

Comment: Don't use onchange method. It's going crazy in MSIE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure what you are going for. If you want to redirect to a page on clicking on the check box you can do this

Specify what url you want to call in your checkbox element using data attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" data-target="http://www.facebook.com" />
```

Script is

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var item=$(this);    
  if(item.is(":checked"))
  {
    window.location.href= item.data("target")
  }    
 });
});
```

Sample JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/45aZ8/2/

**EDIT** : If you want to open it in a new window, use `window.open` method instead of updating the current url

Replace

```
window.location.href= item.data("target")
```

with

```
window.open(item.data("target")
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

**EDIT 3** : **Based on comment** : If you want to load one url on Checked state and load another url on uncheck, you can do like this

Give 2 data attributes for each checkbox. One for checked state and one for unchecked

```
Facebook<input type="checkbox" data-target="http://www.facebook.com" data-target-off="http://www.google.com"  /> <br/>
Twitter<input type="checkbox" data-target="http://www.twitter.com" data-target-off="http://www.asp.net"  /> <br/>
```

And the script is

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var item=$(this);    
  if(item.is(":checked"))
  {
       window.open(item.data("target"))   
  }
  else
  {
      window.open(item.data("target-off"))   
  }        
 });
})
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/45aZ8/5/

Comment: @core1024: yea. Thanks thecodeparadox for jumping in and fixing.

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear, I want the current page to stay open. I want the user to associate the account to a social one and for that I use some URLs. It's just a matter of loading the URL but since the checkboxes are on a profile page it would not be convenient to leave the page. I'm not sure how to handle that with jQuery.

Comment: It looks good but I'm not fluent in jQuery, where should I put my 4 URLs (FB connect and disconnet and Twitter connect and disconnect)? And I'm not sure but I believe this can be linked to the id of the span right? Because I have more checkboxes on this page.

Comment: @Bastian: Check my example http://jsfiddle.net/45aZ8/2/. Use the HTML5 data attribute to store the url

Comment: ok I see but I need to load a different URL when the checkbox is unchecked. Basically when it is checked it should load something like facebook/connect and when it is unchecked it should go to facebook/disconnect and the same for the other one.

Comment: wow, I'm impressed. Great answer. I will stop polluting the comments and mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     if($(this).attr('id') == 'connected_to_facebook') {
        // possibility: 1
     } else {
       // possibility: 3
     }
  } else {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'connected_to_facebook') {
       // possibility: 2
     } else {
       // possibility: 4
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id_connected_to_facebook, #id_connected_to_twitter').click(function(){
   $.post('http://target.url', {this.id:this.checked});
});
```

now you'll get in $_POST either id_connected_to_facebook or id_connected_to_twitter and as a value it would be 1 or 0