# How to make checkboxes go to a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, checkbox

I am using jquery currently and I bind an event handler to checkboxes to bring users to a new page. The problem is that this does not scale well as binding 1500 checkboxes can cause ie8 on slower machines to think the script is not responsive when taking 2-3 seconds to bind these event handlers.

The only other solution I could think of was to use images instead of checkboxes so that they could be surrounded by an  tag instead of having 1500+ event handlers bound. I do not prefer this solution as in general I dont think it's good practice to override the browser's default behavior/style.

Does anyone know a scalable way to bring users to a url when a checkbox is clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453300/jquery-how-do-i-call-a-url-by-checking-a-checkbox

Comment: why not just use anchors since they will be changing pages anyway?

Comment: If you're using jQuery you should look at using delegated events and apply your click handler to a container, or possibly the `<body>` object. However, using a checkbox as a link subverts it's purpose. Why bother to have something that changes state when you're discarding that information as soon as it's checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new jQuery recommandation is to put handlers on a common parent, like `document`, using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function () {
    // your handler code
});
```

The handler isn't attached to your 1500 checkbox but the event naturally bubble to the document that check if the event target match your selector.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the 'onchange' method to check if it's 'checked' and then change the 'document.location.href' to the link you want.

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="if(this.checked) document.location.href='http://www.google.com';"/>Go to google
```

Comment: I believe it is best practice to avoid onchange attribute. Anyway, wouldn't this still bind an event handler for each?

Comment: I prefer this way because it keeps simple to change the url, being able to set dynamically. Yes, we need to avoid 'onchange' attributes because you can't unbind easily, but in this particular case, the checkbox is leading to another url, so events will be killed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'checkbox', function() { // <-- assuming your checkboxes are loaded asynchronously
        window.location= "http://www.example.com";
    });
});
```